# unity_support_test - 3D

Tags: unity, unity3d

I've install Ubuntu 18 in a Virtual Machine. For some reason the command unity_support_test doesn't exist. The directory nux is not created under /usr/lib I don't see anyone with this behavivor on the net. 
Any reason why the install process didn't include unity_support_test?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old question, but I will provide an answer because I was also searching for this and some blogs/tutorials on this topic do not mention that **you have to install nux-tools via**

`sudo apt install nux-tools`